# PostgreSQL v9.3.4 memory usage Issue on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: postgresql, memory-usage

I have DB of size ~16GB Windows Server 2008 R2 (up to date).

We moved from Postgres v9.2.4 to Postgres v9.3.4 and now Postgres v9.3.4 memory usage is growing until is takes all the windows physical memory. On windows start up, physical memory usage is around 13%. In 48H this memory usage will increase to 70% and most of the memory is used by postgres.

But on Postgres v9.2.4 everything was fine, memory usage was reasonable. But I'm not able to understand what's wrong with Postgres v9.3.4.

To keep my application running, I had to restart the server for every 48hrs.

Did anyone had same issue and found any solutions? It will be highly appreciated it someone can help me with this.

Comment: Certainly not a known issue. Can you tell me more about the workload and configuration? Show your `shared_buffers`, `work_mem`, `maintenance_work_mem`, `max_connections`, etc. How do you measure the memory use? What actually happens if it starts using lots of RAM, are there any real effects?

Comment: max_connections = 300
shared_buffers = 512MB
temp_buffers = 256MB
work_mem = 256MB
#maintenance_work_mem = 16MB

The system is running fine for 3 days but in the 4th day the physical memory usage in task manager in over 83% and the next error is stopping my posgresql service.
"CreateProcess call failed: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall. (error code 8)"

Comment: Your work_mem is too high if you're really using all those 300 connections, but I'd expect to see intermittent problems and swapping with that not a gradual growth. I wonder if you've found a memory leak somewhere. Can you tell me more about your workload? What extensions do you use, what kinds of queries do you run? Lots of small queries? What else is running on the same computer? If you restart *PostgreSQL*, not the whole server, does memory use go back down?

Comment: No, we don’t really use all the 300 connections at the same time. Once we had 150 simultaneous connections and so to play it safe we configured it as 300. During the time work memory increases we hardly have 5 simultaneous connections. The workload is like, 70% small & 30% big queries. This is a dedicated machine just for db. **"postgres.exe" "--forkboot" "2880" "-x4"**, **"postgres.exe" "--forkboot" "2904" "-x3"**. These are the two processes which seem to grow gradually and never release memory. The first process is the one which grows very high and takes all the memory.

Comment: Please check pg_stat_activity and see what those processes are doing.

Comment: In pg_stat_activity we don't see these processes. It shows activities that are related to connections, like for each query when we run. But those "-x3" or "-x4" processes are something internal which is growing. We suspect that its something related to Check pointer process. But not sure.

Comment: OK, so the `-x` flags are added by `StartChildProcess` in `postmaster.c`. The `AuxProcType` argument passed is the number afterwards, from an enum in `miscadmin.h`. 3 is the bgwriter, 4 is the checkpointer. So if they're growing, something's certainly wrong. I'm not seeing other reports of this and I'm wondering if there's something different about your query patterns - please describe how you're using Pg in as much detail as possible. Also, any antivirus software present? And please confirm that restarting just PostgreSQL, not the whole server, fixes the load.

Comment: Hi Craig, Our problem was solved. It was related to one of the drivers installed on machine; PostgreSQL had nothing to do with that. More info: [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0b610346-fc53-4b39-8cfd-9737d265c3f4/physical-memory-leak-by-terminated-processes?forum=winservergen). It was caused by aksdf.sys and hardlock.sys  driver files which was installed by Advantage Database Server v7.1 (we never used it though). But for every Postgres connection we had 20Kb of memory leak on machine. Now its removed and server is working fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please post that as an answer-to-self. I had a similar issue with a Logitech webcam driver for a laptop built-in webcam once - it installed a hook DLL that loaded in every process, but it had a race condition with multiple concurrent short lived processes that meant it'd tend to hang `as` processes when I was compiling stuff with mingw. Took some time to track down! Of course, I never did get a response from Logitech to the bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was solved. It was related to couple of the drivers installed on machine; PostgreSQL had nothing to do with that.

To ready more info about this issue: [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0b610346-fc53-4b39-8cfd-9737d265c3f4/physical-memory-leak-by-terminated-processes?forum=winservergen).

It was caused by `aksdf.sys` and `hardlock.sys` driver files which was installed by `Advantage Database Server v7.1` (we never used it though).

Our suspicion went towards PostgreSQL at first because that was the only program which was getting used on that server. So for every PostgreSQL connection, we had a Zombie process consuming 20Kb of physical memory. Hence this continued until whole physical memory was consumed and then after that we had to reboot the machine to make it work.

We used following tools to track this issue:

- RAMMAP (Most helpful)
- PROCESS EXPLORER
- TCPView