# How to diagnose memory usage issues in PostgreSQL 9.5 on a 8GB Windows 2008 Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, postgresql, memory-usage

I have similar symptoms to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/591384/postgresql-v9-3-4-memory-usage-issue-on-windows-server-2008-r2). Our current setup is a **shared** server with 8GB RAM running PostgreSQL 9.5.

> Memory usage is growing until is takes all the windows physical memory. On windows start up, physical memory usage is around 13%. In 48H this memory usage will increase to 70% and most of the memory is used by postgres.

When another user complained that memory usage was too high I cancelled all my queries, to minimal effect. So I restarted the `postgresql-x64` Service and RAM usage went from 7.3 to below 3 GB, and it has been steadily creeping up all day. The current usage of the database has been mostly building a partitioned table of monthly data, each month having around 30M rows, adding indexes and updating a column, all of which takes multiple hours.

Relevant configuration parameters

```
max_connections = 24
effective_cache_size = 2GB
shared_buffers = 128MB
work_mem = 8MB
```

My current solution would be to restart the `postgresql` service every morning but this is going to really slow down this querying. I tried searching for the programs mentioned in the question above but they don't exist. Windows Update hasn't been run in a while, but how else should I be diagnosing this memory issue?

Comment: From RamMap, seems over 2GB of data are being loaded into Standby memory and this isn't being freed up for other processes.

Comment: Another 2.25GB are under the "Mapped File" Active heading, but can't definitely determine what is consuming the bulk of that